# Is there a method to set the value for the Return code (RTNCDE) parameter of the Retrieve Job Attributes (RTVJOBA) command

Tags: ibm-midrange

The following documents that the **Return Code (RTNCDE)** value available from the **Retrieve Job Attribute (RTVJOBA)** command is returned as `DECIMAL(5, 0)` and later clarifies in the thread-safety information\table that the value is actually called [more accurately to be referred to as] the **Program Return Code** and that the value is not thread-safe, from which we can conclude safely that there is no thread-specific support for setting this value:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/cl/rtvjoba.htm#RTVJOBA.RTNCDE

> **Retrieve Job Attributes (RTVJOBA)**
>   
> `CL var for RTNCDE (5 0) (RTNCDE)`
>   Specifies the name of the CL variable that receives the 5-digit decimal return code of an RPG, COBOL, DFU, or sort utility program. The return code is set by these programs before they return to the programs that call them. The return code indicates the completion status of the last program (of these types) that has completed processing within the job, as follows:
> ...
>   
> **Attribute Scope and Thread Safety Table:**
>   `Attribute                                            Scope    Threadsafe`
>   `Program return code (RTNCDE)                         Job          No`

Visiting the [unlikely drill-down\navigation of *Programming->Control language->CL programming->Compiling CL source program->Return code summary*] can be found some documentation for the use of that retrieved value; an unlikely place, because the CL compilers apparently do not set the value, nor do CL procedures or programs:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rbam6/retcs.htm

> **Return code summary**
>   
>   A return code can be returned using the Return code (RTNCDE) parameter on the Retrieve Job Attributes (RTVJOBA) command.
>   
>   The return code is a 5-digit decimal value with no decimal positions (12345. for example). The decimal value indicates the status of called programs. CL programs do not set the return code. However, you can retrieve the current value of the return code as set by another program in a CL program. You can do this by using the RTNCDE parameter of the Retrieve Job Attributes (RTVJOBA) command.
>   
>   The following list summarizes the return codes used by languages supported on the IBM® i operating system:
> ...

In the above list [omitted from the quoted docs] are the RPG compilers and program, COBOL compilers and programs, and C programs. Missing from the above list is CL compilers or CL; as well, any mention of **DFU** programs and the **Sort Utility** feature, which are both mentioned in the prior included doc reference.  The only mention of CL is the prior mention of *but you can use RTVJOBA* to read the value... OK, but only as **returned by other** programs and compilers, not what was the effective return code of the CL procedure or program I just called!

So... And what I want to know, is despite that CL does not set the value [**good** because I want to have my CL program set the value], can a CL program be used to set the value **because** the CL program does not do so implicitly; conspicuously, per the compiled run-time object does not [¿and does not intend to?] include any code to set a return code?

If nothing else [likely, as the most probable response will be the undesirable recommendation to "Write a program with system-state to modify the value...", then please only if also accompanied by documentation [by your own research; I realize there is unlikely to be any public documentation] of the location of the value [for posterity as I am unlikely to actually code anything], presumably as a value stored in the Process Control Space (PCS); see: DMPSYSOBJ *PCS

The following, as the most likely method capable, documents nothing about the ability to change the Return Code:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/apis/qwtchgjb.htm

> **Change Job (QWTCHGJB) API**

P.S. if someone knows of and could provide a link to the documentation alluded for the **Product Return Code** in the following link, specifically for the ILE CL Compiler, so I might learn more about that value; another return-code, but somewhat off-topic to my question:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/apis/WMAttrDesc.htm

> **Product return code.** The return code set by the compiler for Integrated Language Environment® (ILE) languages. Refer to the appropriate ILE-conforming language manual for possible values. This field is scoped to the job and represents the most recent return code set by any thread within the job.
> ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I forgot that you wanted a program to set it. The one I posted first just retrieves it.

This program will set the "Language/Utility return code" from the "LU Work Area" which is the one that is set by OPM and ILE RPG. It's the same return code that shows on page 1 of DSPJOB.

I think OPM COBOL sets this return code, but if I recall correctly, ILE COBOL sets one of the other return codes in the LU work area. ILE C also sets one of the other return codes.

```
pgm
    /*------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* From QSYSINC/H MILIB:                                      */
    /*                                                            */
    /* typedef volatile struct _LU_Work_Area_T {                  */
    /*   short LU_RC;             -- Language/Utility return code */
    /*   ...                                                      */
    /* } _LU_Work_Area_T;                                         */
    /* ...                                                        */
    /* _SPCPTR  _LUWRKA    ( void );                              */
    /*------------------------------------------------------------*/
    dcl &luwrka_p type(*ptr)
    dcl &luwrka   type(*char) stg(*based) basptr(&luwrka_p)
      dcl &lu_rc  type(*int) len(2) +
                  stg(*defined) defvar(&luwrka 1)

    callprc '_LUWRKA' rtnval(&luwrka_p)
    chgvar &lu_rc 5

endpgm
```

Comment: The importance of consistency in naming seems all-too-often overlooked within IBM :-( <br>Just curious, does the Return Value (RTNVAL) really need to specify a basing pointer, or would the RtnVal operate like parameters for which implicit pass-by-reference achieves the same effect? Per msg MCH3203 T/QBNCRTMD and msg CWX9001 rc0001, I infer not. As such, coding that CL is not an option in v5r3. But if I code that same function in RPG, then that program or procedure would end up overwriting the return code that I just set, so I would have to code in ILE COBOL or ILE C instead, on that release?

Comment: I think the RTNVAL has to specify a basing pointer. I don't think there's any language that has implicit "return by reference". You're right, you couldn't code this in CL, it has to be CLLE to make the bound call.

Setting the return code is part of the RPG cycle, so ILE RPG procedures don't set it. 

(Also, RPG linear main programs (MAIN H spec keyword) don't set it, but linear main programs are only available starting in v6r1.)

Comment: I did of course mean to imply ILE CL; the program QBNCRTMD implies a failed attempt to Create Bound CL Program (CRTBNDCL). The issue with v5r3 is the lack of both the Storage (STG) parameter keyword and special value *PTR for the Type (TYPE) parameter kwd for the Declare (DCL) in CL. I will try binding an RPG procedure that mimics above CLLE source, and presuming success, I will return to mark this question as answered. Given this "Language/Utility return code" is the same as the "Program return code", still curious about the "Product return code";likely compiler related, so who better to ask?

Comment: OK. Thanks. My RPG version worked splendidly. I learned however, that the WRKJOB OPTION(*STSA) allows for only a two-digit output, and shows '++' when the value is too large. No matter, I just wanted to play with the value retrieved by RTVJOBA, which is 05P00.

Comment: I don't know much about the "Product Return Code". RPG doesn't use either the Product RC or the User RC, either in the compiler and runtime, or in the generated programs. Although the compiler may inadvertently set the Product RC when it returns since it's written in C. This page talks about the Product Return Code along with a warning in the last bullet about how it might not be reliable. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/CEE4SETRC.htm. I think that warning might apply to any of those return codes.

Comment: I believe that is the User Return Code from the WM attributes docs; there is the warning there about the unpredictable nature because the pervasiveness of C and C++ code in the OS [and LPPs]; if so, again with the *inconsistent* naming, where they call that "the program return code" :-( I wonder how I missed that doc link in my search for Return Code in the KnowledgeCenter; hmm, must be that bug where when I click "next 20" I never seem to get many more links even though the numbers keep incrementing. Regardless, Thanks much... Again.